# How to access the redux store inside a component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm totally new to redux and here I'm trying display my data in a table. I should pass the data set to another component. I know how to get data to the redux store. What I don't know is how to pass them to a component as a prop. Can anyone please help me?

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import TicketTable from '../../components/TicketTable/TicketTable';
import { ticketData } from './dummyData';
import { getTicketList } from './actions/TicketActions';

import axios from 'axios';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import './Home.scss';

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // this.props.getTicketList();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getTicketList();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        <TicketTable data={ticketData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default connect(
  (state) => ({ ...state.ViewTickets.ticketsList.data.content }),
  (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({ getTicketList }, dispatch)
)(Home);
```

I want to pass `state.ViewTickets.ticketsList.data.content` as a prop to `TicketTable`

Comment: [Did you look at examples in react-redux?](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually my first advice is try use Hook component,
I dont know your redux codes but if u want try like this;

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        'your state name ': state.'Your reducer name'
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: {
            'your action name' ': bindActionCreators('your action'.'your action child', dispatch)
        }
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CartSummary)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just try to use
`(state) => {return state.ViewTickets.ticketsList.data.content; },`